# Sql query for deleting rows before a certain year

Tags: mysql

How can I delete all the rows before a certain year(say 2012) in MySQL, where the date column is in DATETIME format?
ex:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE date<2012;
```

Is not working.

Comment: u r want to consider only year?make it clear first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE date < '2012-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Comment: No Problem :) If you find this answer useful, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the Tick button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
DELETE FROM `tablename` where YEAR(`date`) < '2012'
```

Comment: Results in full table scan even when `date` is an indexed column.